# Scala Slick combining Rep sub queries into one re

Tags: scala, slick

I sum up totals in two different database tables:

```
val sum1Query: Rep[Int] = tableQuery1.map(_.amount).sum.ifNull(0)
val sum2Query: Rep[Int] = tableQuery2.map(_.amount).sum.ifNull(0)

for {
  sum1 <- sum1Query.result
  sum2 <- sum2Query.result
} yield {
  sum1 + sum2
}
```

This runs 2 SQL queries to the database each time `.result` is called. I am looking for a way to make it use only one SQL query.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
for {
  sum1 <- sum1Query
  sum2 <- sum2Query
} yield {
  sum1 + sum2
}.result
```

Any ideas on how to do it in Slick other than using plain SQL query?

Comment: Possible solution is to wrap it in a query that returns one row:
tableQuery3.filter(_.id === 1).map { _ =>
  sum1 + sum2
}.result.headOption

But would lovve to find something better lookig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `.result` creates a `DBIO` action which is a SQL statement. The trick to reducing the number of actions is to find a way to combine two queries (or two `Rep`s) together into one action.

In your case you could zip the two queries:

```
val sum1 = table1.map(_.amount).sum.ifNull(0)
val sum2 = table2.map(_.amount).sum.ifNull(0)
val query = sum1.zip(sum2)
```

When run the `query.result` you'll execute a single query something like:

```
select ifnull(x2.x3,0), ifnull(x4.x5,0) 
from 
  (select sum("amount") as x3 from "table_1") x2, 
  (select sum("amount") as x5 from "table_2") x4
```

...which will result in a tuple of the two values.

However, as you've already just got a `Rep[Int]` you can use `+` in the database:

```
val query = sum1 + sum2
```

...which will be a query along the lines of:

```
select ifnull(x2.x3,0) + ifnull(x4.x5,0) 
from 
 (select sum("amount") as x3 from "table_1") x2, 
 (select sum("amount") as x5 from "table_2") x4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it like this:

```
(sum1 + sum2).result
```